# Select from mysql is not working in jQuery fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fancybox

Fancybox script POST my form data to go.php page then open go.php in fancybox iframe

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
        $.post('go.php', $(this).parent().serialize())
            .done(function() {
                $.fancybox.open({
                    href : 'go.php',
                    type : 'iframe',
                    padding : 5
                });
            });
    });
});
</script>

<select name="country">
<option value="US">US</option>
<option value="EU">EU</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="fancybox-manual-b"/>
```

in go.php, I receive the POST data from the form correctly and when I try to insert this data into DB, it's been inserted correctly too!
But now I want to select * from my DB table to echo all the data in the table where column = POST data, but this query doesn't work!

```
<?php
$country = $_POST[country];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO calculator (country) VALUES ('$country')"); //Works Correctly

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calculator WHERE country='$country' ORDER BY ID ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['ID']." ".$row['country'];
} //Nothing appear
?>
```

Comment: The query looks fine.Try to run query on sql server and check what you got.

Comment: Please consider using MySQLi and Prepared statements to make your DB queries, as this is wide open for SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use jquery ajax to send form data to the php page with POST method then receive back any printed data from the php page in the ajax instead of the console.
We will open the fancybox iframe into ajax success instead of the console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'go.php',
            data: $(this).parent().serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $.fancybox(data);   
            },
            fail:function(data){console.info(data)}
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this method,

```
$country = $_POST[country];
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO calculator (country) VALUES ('$country')")); 
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calculator WHERE country='$country' ORDER BY ID ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['ID']." ".$row['country'];
}
}
```

I used the same code you shared. But added an additional `if` loop on `mysql_query` part. It will make sure your `select` works after data being inserted.

Comment: Same result, insert works correctly and the select doesn't work.. the problem is not from the select, we are using the ajax jquery in a wrong way...

Comment: Same result...nothing appeared...anything was sent via this jquery could be executed in mysql only as server side but never echo anything to the client side, I think the result of the ajax returns back to html file and I could print it out there in "success console"